# Error: '\R' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "C:\R"

Tags: r

I am running Windows XP Pro and R Version 2.15.1  R is installed in the following folder:

> C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.1

I am trying to create a function that reads in a .csv file like so:

```
xxx <- function(id, directory, summarize = FALSE) {
    data <- read.table('C:\xxx\classes\R_Prog\specdata\data.csv')
    head(data)
}
```

I get the error

> Error: '\R' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "C:\R"

Is there a problem with my directory structure / folder naming conventions?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You have to escape the `\` since it is itself an escape character.

```
read.table('C:\\xxx\\classes\\R_Prog\\specdata\\data.csv') head(data) }
```

Comment: Thanks @Jordan! very good solution

Answer (score 20):

As nobody suggested a forward slash yet, allow me to do so:

```
R> list.files("C:/opt", pattern="R")
[1] "R-current"  "R-library"  "R-local215" "RStudio"    "Rtools"    
R>
```

I find forward slashes "easier on the eye" as it makes paths more consistent across OSs, and you do not need to escape them either.  Which means you save a whole byte each time. Yippie.

Answer (score 8):

Noone has suggested `file.path` yet. This will concatenate a string together to form a file path using a platform specific separator ( default is `/` on windows)

```
file.path('c:', 'xxx', 'classes', 'R_prog','specdata', 'data.csv')
## [1] "c:/xxx/classes/R_prog/specdata/data.csv"
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape your backslashes. try doubling them: c:\\xxx\\classes\\R_Prog\\ etc.

Answer (score -3):

I've found that both the \ (escaping the )

```
C:\\xxx\\classes\\R_Prog\\specdata\\data.csv
```

and the / solutions work:

```
C:/xxx/classes/R_prog/specdata/data.csv
```

I personally find it easier to use the latter.

Comment: This answer does not add any new information than what the other answers already give.